# apache zookeeper ask server RAM

Tags: resources, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

Is it possible to use zookeeper to monitor the server resources or to retrieve a number representing the total RAM available?

Answer (score 2):

**Apache Zookeeper** is not a monitoring tool, it's a distributed manager for configuration sharing, naming and synchronization.

Here is a good description of what Apache Zookeeper is and how it can be used - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8864303/2453586

You can make a workaround and write a script that will check the amount of available RAM every N minutes/seconds (via **cron** or like a **deamonized process**) on each local machine and write this value to Zookeeper **znode**, like **zookeeper_host:2181/ram/host1/available**. But it's not a good idea.

It's more likely to use a specific tools like Zabbix, Nagios or Gangila for memory monitoring purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like [jmx](http://wiki.gxtechnical.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Monitoring%20Memory%20Management%20with%20JMX,).