# zookeeper synchronization and backup strageties

Tags: backup, apache-zookeeper, failover

I am new to Zookeeper and have some doubts:

1. when a leader server is down, what's the backup strategy? does some random follower server become leader server automatically?
2. how much delay will the population of change from the leader server to the follower server? this is due to that the write operation only happens to the leader server and it will populate to the follower server with next state. I am just wondering what's the strategy of sync between leader server and follower servers and how often this happens?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes when the leader server is down one of the follower server
   becomes master automatically .In zookeepers an ensemble of 2N+1
   servers can take care of N server failure . For creating an ensemble
   check :
   [what is zookeeper port and its usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168541/what-is-zookeeper-port-and-its-usage/18186224#18186224)
2. The delay depends on the parameter u set in /con/zoo.cfg file .The main parameter is the "ticktime" .This parameter is a kind of heartbeat parameter betwwen the servers.For sync internally it uses Zab protocol .You can check

[Zookeeper Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920821/zookeeper-working)

[Distributed Application using Zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066482/distributed-application-using-zookeeper)