# Can I query any zookeeper node to get any data?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have a small zookeeper cluster of 3 nodes.  I also have another software  that needs to be configured to talk to zookeeper, also running in a cluster of 3 nodes, on the same host.

I don't know anything about how zookeeper works.  Do I have to configure this other software to talk to all hosts, or should it work to just configure it to talk to localhost zookeeper?

Put another way, can a query to any zookeeper node to get any data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had a ZooKeeper cluster, so you can query to any ZooKeeper node and get eventually consistent data.

For `how ZooKeeper works` you can check this awesome post here:[Explaining Apache ZooKeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662995/explaining-apache-zookeeper)

A lots of good projects use ZooKeeper as a backbone: HBase, Kafka, please Google it, and learn from those projects for more digest.