# Configuration Settings Service/Repository: Are They Used in a Real World

Tags: configuration-management, continuous-delivery, escape-server

I’m currently enjoying reading "Continuous Delivery: Reliable Software Releases Through Build, Test, and Deployment Automation" and the part that caught my attention is that on managing configuration settings for applications.

What's proposed in the book is that all configuration settings are externalized and centralized in a repository of some sort, be it an LDAP directory, [ESCAPE Server](http://blog.chris-read.net/2009/02/13/introducing-escape/) or somesuch and then retrieved from there.

This sounds really compelling to me as this approach can provide a number of tangible benefits, but after Googling around for a bit it seems to me that this is not exactly a widespread approach.

I know there is a [Twelve-Factor App](http://12factor.net/config) article on this subject, but it suggests using environment variables instead of a centralized repository. This approach seems to be the most commonly used one, but it feels like a dirty one compared to a repository-based solution.

So, is the central-configuration-repository approach used in any significant manner in a real world, and if not -- what are the reasons for this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Zookeeper is frequently used for managing config variables:

http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/recipes.html#sc_outOfTheBox

[Real World Use of Zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479442/real-world-use-of-zookeeper)

Doozer looks interesting as well:

https://github.com/ha/doozerd

And here is RESTful wrapper over Git inspired by the same text you refer to:

http://www.andycaine.com/configuration-management-with-restful-git/

Finally, env vars may feel dirty but they are actually quite a clean approach

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars