# Is zookeeper used only for kafka if others then can some one give realtime example?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

While I am creating cluster setup for `kafka` I came to know zookeeper quorum set up  is needed for coordination between `kafka` brokers.

Are there any other scenarios where we use zookeeper other than only for `kafka` setup in real time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real World Use of Zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479442/real-world-use-of-zookeeper)

Answer (score 0):

This link lists many applications and organisations using ZooKeeper

https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.2/zookeeperUseCases.html

ZooKeeper is used with many Apache projects and is a distributed coordination service used to manage a large set of hosts. In simple terms, Zookeeper allows workers to get on with their jobs and handles all the other complexities i.e. if a leader goes down, alerting the workers, electing a new leader etc.